# Handling URI reserved characters for GET requests

Tags: angular, get, uri, backend

I'm making GET requests from my angular service by replacing reserved characters using `encodeURIComponent` so that it is sent to URL like

```
http://localhost:4200/api/verifiers/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.web.com%2Fdev%2F0/services/xx%3Ayy%3AV00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000%23read-device
```

However when my FastAPI backend receive the request it will display a `404 Not Found` error because some characters like `%2F` are recognized as `/` so the controller fails at parsing the URL related to the method that should handle the request.

For example the above URL is received from my backend as

```
/verifiers/https%3A//www.web.com/dev/0/services/xx%3Ayy%3AV00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000%23read-device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by postfixing `:path` in the URL path of the handlers

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent at the frontend ... use decodeURIComponent at the backend to descramble it

Comment: the problem is that `FastAPI` will automatically recognize `%2F` as `/` and it says that there is no handler for that URL